# Web developing noob - help needed for css

Tags: html, css

I am extreme beginner and I have this dumb problem.
So I wrote a css file and html file.

HTML :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>

                  <img 
            src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/67/b2/a9/67b2a9ba5e85822f237caae92111e938.gif" 
           width="300" id="para1">
                  <p>Paragraph</p>

        </body>
    </html>
```

I did this for my css file

```
p {
    color: red;
}
```

When I save and refresh my website, the html shows up.

The css doesnt show  up like the paragraph doesnt change red. I also want to change the position of the image.

Please help!

I also want to know about indenting please.

Also should for website developing, should I learn css and html at the same time, or like html for 1 year, and then css for one year, because im learning javascript like in a 2 years, next year.

Comment: You must link your CSS

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

Comment: You can find a lot of css guide on the internet. Try to search and code code code

Comment: Code for the html file : <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        </head>
        <body>

            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/67/b2/a9/67b2a9ba5e85822f237caae92111e938.gif" width="300" id="para1">
            <p>Paragraph</p>








        </body>
    </html>

Code for the css file : 

p {
    color:red;
}

Also please try and answer the question on the bottom.

Comment: Congrats ! Don't forget to accept an answer if one helps you.

Answer (score 3):

You must tell your HMTL page where to find your CSS.
To do that you have to add `link` tag into your `head` tag using:

```
<head>
    <link href="/path/to/your/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

`<link>`: The External Resource Link element

> The  HTML element specifies relationships between the current
> document and an external resource. This element is most commonly used
> to link to stylesheets, but is also used to establish site icons (both
> "favicon" style icons and icons for the home screen and apps on mobile
> devices) among other things.

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

In your case if your css file named `style.css` and  `your index.html` file are on the same folder, your html should look like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/67/b2/a9/67b2a9ba5e85822f237caae92111e938.gif" width="300" id="para1">
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</body>

</html>
```

> The  HTML element contains machine-readable information
> (metadata) about the document, like its title, scripts, and style
> sheets.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head

If you want to use [inline css](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) you have to put your `<style>` tag between your `<head>` tag to make it processed by HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    p {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/67/b2/a9/67b2a9ba5e85822f237caae92111e938.gif" width="300" id="para1">
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback, and help tho, I dont really understand how to use the link tag and what to do, and also if you can, can you answer the question I put on the very very bottom.

Comment: Take a look at the edit, if my answer is ok, tell us :)

Comment: Well, ok but I still don't understand why my css page doesn't work like I have to write the css in the html file, like why is that, why cant i write it in the css file?

Comment: Take a look at the edit, again :) Added inline css method

Answer (score 0):

> Also should for website developing, should I learn css and html at the
> same time, or like html for 1 year, and then css for one year, because
> im learning javascript like in a 2 years, next year.

Well, HTML, CSS & JS are the fabric of the front end so my advice is why not all three at the same time? They each compliment each other and after 3 years studying you will have understood more about them than focusing your time and energy learning each as separate entities.

Think of HTML as your initial sketch (your structure), CSS as painting your sketch (your make-up and beautifier), and JS as making your painting come to life (your functional and interactive parts). Simply put, it's more fun with working with all 3

Comment: Thanks so much! I have already tried learning js but after like 1 day I lost all interest, but I feel I should learn  html and css first , as that is the building blocks on a website. To be honest, I really feel like learning javascript like next year like in 365 days from today, or something.